# Kinetic Js clear a layer

Tags: javascript

I am looking a way to delete a layer on kinetic js..
I think it was a simple task i have try some code such as node.remove() or layer.remove(node) but really can't figure it out.

here's the sample code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 239,
        y: 75,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(rect);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);

function delete()
    {
    layer.remove();

    }
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="delete()">Delete</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't figured it out why my delete() function won't work.
someone know what I do wrong?
thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've never needed to remove a whole layer. I clear it and reuse it.

layer.removeChildren();

or

to remove just specific content like (groups) or (lines) or (images) or whatever...

```
console.dir(layer);  // initial check -- look at (children)...

    var groups = $('#layerID').find('Group');
    groups.each(function(group) {

        group.destroy(); or.... 
        group.remove();

    });

console.dir(layer);  // verify it worked (look at children again... a bunch were removed)
```